# How do I use a variable in a regex when doing a string.scan?

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to use a string variable in my regex when I scan through a document:

```ruby
urlstring = "example.com"
scanresult = @doc.scan(/variable text in urlstring(.*?)link-text/)
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`#{}` are interpreted almost like in `""` in regex literal.

is `@doc.scan /#{urlstring}(.*?)link-text/` what you want?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
urlstring = "example.com" scanresult = @doc.scan(/variable text in #{urlstring}(.*?)link-text/)
```

Putting the variable between `#{..}`